# Obx Bad state: No element & setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build

Tags: flutter, dart, get

So I already read a bit about the problem above but I still can't figure it out.

So I have three pages.

the one page that contains an Obx that causes my problems

```
    class Zahlungsmethode extends StatefulWidget {
  final ACUser? acUser;
  const Zahlungsmethode({super.key, this.acUser});

  @override
  State<Zahlungsmethode> createState() => _ZahlungsmethodeState();
}

class _ZahlungsmethodeState extends State<Zahlungsmethode> {
  final CartController cartController = Get.find();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          AppBarSmall(),
          Obx(
            () => Container(
              height: 120,
              width: 300,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  border: Border.all(color: const Color(0xffF6CD9D))),
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  const SizedBox(
                    height: 5,
                  ),
                  Text("Artikel: ${cartController.total}€"),
                  const SizedBox(
                    height: 5,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Then An App Bar:

```
AppBarSmall(),
```

that's inside of the page and contains an IconButton that navigates to another screen

```
              onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (BuildContext context) => UserData())),
```

The screen that it navigates to doesn't contain any specialties. I just want to execute the function below:

```
  Future<void> signOut(context) async {
showDialog(
    context: context,
    barrierDismissible: false,
    builder: (context) => const Center(
          child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
        ));
await FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut();
if (user == null) {
  isB2C.value = true;
  cartController.anzahl.value = 0;
  cartController.products.clear();
  addCView();

  Future.delayed(Duration.zero, () async {
    Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (BuildContext context) =>
            const HomePage(selectedIndex: 0)));
  });
}
```

}

It shows me the circular progress Indicator and everything but when it has to navigate to the home page I get the error. I tested a bit and removed the Obx, after that everything worked fine then. But I need it because the variable it contains updates regularly.

Also much weirder is that I can execute the function everywhere in my Application, but when I just visited the screen that contains the Obx once, the function will throw the error always, even if I navigate back to the home screen and call the function from there

Here The Error:

> The following StateError was thrown building Obx(has builder, dirty,
> state: _ObxState#b997e): Bad state: No element
>
> The relevant error-causing widget was:   Obx
> Obx:file:///Users/nikitareichert/Desktop/AngerComponents2/Website/angercomponents/lib/Checkout/zahlungsmethode.d
> art:46:11
> Another exception was thrown: setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build.

Comment: Try to create a variable from your cartController.total in your Obx block. Sometimes I had same issue, I guess because of the String interpolation.

Comment: Will do that, is that a know flaw from get?

Comment: Make sure you are not updating any value while widgets are binding

Comment: Ah in my case Im updating them, can I somehow say that they shouldn't be binding when Im updating the value?